# Infinite scrolling in a Rails app

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, infinite-scroll

I'm using this https://github.com/jney/jquery.pageless.demo/tree/master/example.rails3 plugin to achieve an infinite scrolling effect into my application. The developer had mentioned in his readme file to just copy this

```
               $('#container1').pageless({ 
                 totalPages: 5,
                 url: 'shirts/first',
                 loaderMsg: 'Loading more results'
               });
```

But that didn't work. Then I downloaded his demo and looked into his code and found out I had to even write this in my controller

```
           if request.xhr?
             sleep(1)
             render :partial => 'shirts/first'
           end
```

Can someone please explain the above code to me? How are the javascript code and the above are related? I have some idea about the working but i'm not entirely sure, so anyone with a good hold on this matter, could you please explain me?

Answer (score 1):

When an AJAX request is made, it adds a special X-Requested-With header which you can check for. Essentially what the code is doing is:

```
if request.xhr? #Check for the X-Requested-With Header
  sleep(1) #Wait for 1 second
  render :partial => 'shirts/first' #Insert the partial into the container
end
```

It would probably be educational to implement this from scratch using jQuery as it wouldn't be that difficult and would make some parts of this a lot more obvious to you.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your advice. Will certainly do!